# move the key between frames - Maya Graph Editor

Tags: python, graph, key, frame, maya

I have many keys in Graph Editor, After scaling them, Maya has moved some of them between frames, (frame 5,37-4'54-...). I know how to move them one by one but I would like to create any script to put them one frame after o before.

[image: img]

Select All keys - click right - Snap option is not enough

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to the [selectKey](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__CommandsPython_selectKey_html) and [keyframe](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__CommandsPython_keyframe_html) commands.

You could do something like this:

```py
from maya import cmds

# Select the keys to be moved based on a time interval.
# For example the following commands will select keys between 5.01 and 5.99.
# Customize the interval and object/attributes based on your need.
cmds.selectKey(clear=True)
cmds.selectKey('pSphere1.tx', add=True, keyframe=True, time=(5.01, 5.99))
cmds.selectKey('pSphere1.ty', add=True, keyframe=True, time=(5.01, 5.99))
cmds.selectKey('pSphere1.tz', add=True, keyframe=True, time=(5.01, 5.99))

# Change the time of the selected keys to the correct value (for example 5.0)
cmds.keyframe(animation='keys', option='over', absolute=True, timeChange=5.0)
```